# Selenium is not returning all rows from a table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a list of all market zones in Binance and I am using selenium for that. Basically, I click on the zones item and then order all coins by name, I put a time.sleep just to wait for the page to finish loading, but when I try to get all elements, it returns just the first twelve ones. I tried with different selectors, but it also did not work.
What could be happening?

```
driver.get("https://www.binance.com/en/markets")

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__APP"]/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div')
button.click()
button_all = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__APP"]/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/button[1]')
button_all.click()
button_order = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__APP"]/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div')
button_order.click()

time.sleep(1)
data_cryptos = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div .css-4cffwv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on the site is that it's lazy loading of sorts. It only stores and displays so many rows at a time. As you scroll down, the rows above fall off and the rows below appear. You would have to scroll down, scraping as you go, and then clean up the duplicates from your list to make sure you get all of them.

Rather than do all that, you can use requests and get all of them much quicker than you can with Selenium.

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.binance.com/bapi/composite/v1/public/marketing/symbol/list")
json = r.json()
for msg in json["data"]:
    print("name: ", msg["name"])
```

This prints

```
name:  1INCH
name:  AAVE
name:  ACM
name:  ADA
name:  ADX
....
```

---

How to get the URL for the requests call...

Steps:

1. Load https://www.binance.com/en/markets in Chrome.
2. Press F12 to open the devtools.
3. Across the top of the devtools, there are tabs... Elements, Console, Sources, Network, ... click Network.
4. In the filter area, click XHR.
5. Refresh the page so that the network traffic is displayed.
6. I clicked through each of the rows looking for the request that returned the page data that I was interested in. I just opened each one and looked for the names of the markets from the page, e.g. 1INCH, AAVE, etc.
7. Once I found that page URL under "list", I right-clicked on "list" and Copy > Copy link address.
8. I opened a new browser tab and pasted in the address I just copied and saw that it was JSON. You can either use the Network tab in Chrome to see the format of the data but sometimes it's easier to look at it in an online beautifier like https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer.
9. Once you have the JSON formatted where it's readable, you just have to figure out where the data is that you want. There is LOTS of data in there. The market names are under data > name but you can get up to 20 other bits of info for each market from that list.

[image: Network tab with XHR filtered]

Comment: Can you share the path how you find that exact API link from API documentation

Comment: Is it possible to stop the loading on the page and then get all the list using selenium?
Besides that, how did you got this exact URL?

Comment: I don't know that page but as far as I know, there is no way to stop the loading on the page. It's a way many websites control the load speed of a really large page. They do it in chunks.

Comment: Give me a minute and I'll update my answer with how I found the URL.

Comment: I didn't get your 7th point where to find list??

Comment: @BhavyaParikh You clicked XHR to filter? Look right below that under the Name column. You might have to scroll down but "list" is in that list of names.

Comment: @BhavyaParikh I've added a photo with the relevant tabs, list, etc. highlighted

Comment: Great effort @JeffC learn a lot from it! thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you find an answer or question useful, upvote it... not just my answer but any question/answer. It shows the author you appreciate their work and it also signals others that you think this is a quality answer, etc.